# Operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data

Tags: wcf

I am getting this error on my wcf service call:

`A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.`

I have been through a lot of settings regarding size of responses, including these:

`dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"

serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="100"`

`readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"`

`sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" name="netTcpBindingDefault" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"`

I have also set up the diagnonstics tool that can be configured on both client and server/service. It is from this i got the error message:

A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.

If I limit my call to just return 1 record from the database it works fine, but if I increase that to just 10 it will fail with the mentioned error. (It should in production return 250 records)

Can anyone help me figure why it keeps throwing this message.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I am afraid it is of not much help as the problem went away when we moved to new servers.